# Matching two list of unequal length

Tags: r, match, mapply

I am trying to match the values in 2 lists only where the variable names are the same between list. I would like the result to be a list the length of the longer list filled with count of total matches.

```
jac <- structure(list(s1 = "a", s2 = c("b", "c", "d"), s3 = 5), 
                 .Names = c("s1", "s2", "s3"))

larger <- structure(list(s1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "a", class = "factor"), 
          s2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
          s3 = c(1, 2, 7)), .Names = c("s1", "s2", "s3"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using `mapply(FUN = pmatch, jac, larger)` which gives me a correct total but not in the format that I would like below:

```
s1  s2  s3  s1result    s2result    s3result
a   c   1   1   2   NA
a   b   2   1   1   NA
a   c   7   1   3   NA
```

However, I don't think pmatch will ensure the name matching in every situation so I wrote a function that I am still having issues with:

```
prodMatch <- function(jac,larger){
      for(i in 1:nrow(larger)){
          if(names(jac)[i] %in% names(larger[i])){
               r[i] <- jac %in% larger[i]
               r
          }
     }
}
```

Can anyone help out?

Another dataset that causes one to not be a multiple of the ohter:

```
 larger2 <- 
    structure(list(s1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "a"), 
        s2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "c"), 
        s3 = c(1, 2, 7), s4 = c(8, 9, 10)), .Names = c("s1", "s2", 
    "s3", "s4"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapply` returns a list of matching index, you can convert it to a data frame simply using `as.data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(mapply(match, jac, larger))
#   s1 s2 s3
# 1  1  2 NA
# 2  1  1 NA
# 3  1  3 NA
```

And `cbind` the result with `larger` gives what you expected:

```
cbind(larger, 
      setNames(as.data.frame(mapply(match, jac, larger)), 
               paste(names(jac), "result", sep = "")))

#  s1 s2 s3 s1result s2result s3result
#1  a  c  1        1        2       NA
#2  a  b  2        1        1       NA
#3  a  d  7        1        3       NA
```

*Update*: To take care of the cases where the name of the two lists don't match, we can loop through the `larger` and it's name simultaneously and extract the elements from `jac` as follows:

```
as.data.frame(
    mapply(function(col, name) { 
        m <- match(jac[[name]], col)
        if(length(m) == 0) NA else m  # if the name doesn't exist in jac return NA as well
        }, larger, names(larger)))

#  s1 s2 s3
#1  1  2 NA
#2  1  1 NA
#3  1  3 NA
```

Comment: I will be dealing with many rows and would like to use data.table if possible. Does data.table have an equivalent to your suggestion?

Comment: You can use `as.data.table` for converting to `data.table`.

Comment: when using 'match' that will find matching indices even if the names of the columns don't match, correct? That might be a problem if I have a matching value in columns with different names, no?

Comment: I am assuming you have already aligned the names of the two lists. If they are not matched previously, you can loop through the larger list and its names and match with the corresponding element of `jac`. See the update.

Comment: I do have an issue with your code when the larger list is not a multiple of the smaller. I added such a larger dataset to my post called larger2. Is there a way around this error:   Warning message:
In mapply(match, jac, larger) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter